# Oracle BINARY_FLOAT: 2 integers give same value?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table full of 10-digit integers and thought to speed up queries/math in Oracle by storing them as BINARY_FLOAT.  That's more CPU-friendly than NUMBER and won't take as much space (I think), which means more data in memory.

However, it appears that BINARY_FLOAT yields the same bytes (and hence value) for two different numbers...which obviously won't work.

Example:

```
SQL> select dump(to_binary_float(25185387)) from dual;

DUMP(TO_BINARY_FLOAT(2518538
----------------------------
Typ=100 Len=4: 203,192,38,54

SQL> select dump(to_binary_float(25185388)) from dual;

DUMP(TO_BINARY_FLOAT(2518538
----------------------------
Typ=100 Len=4: 203,192,38,54

SQL> CREATE TABLE blah ( somenum BINARY_FLOAT );
Table created.

SQL> insert into blah (somenum) values (25185387);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into blah (somenum) values (25185388);

1 row created.

SQL> select somenum from blah;

   SOMENUM
----------
2.519E+007
2.519E+007

SQL> select to_number(somenum) from blah;

TO_NUMBER(SOMENUM)
------------------
          25185388
          25185388

SQL> select dump(somenum) from blah;

DUMP(SOMENUM)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=100 Len=4: 203,192,38,54
Typ=100 Len=4: 203,192,38,54
```

I expected that if I got into floating point, I might have some problem, but these are integers.  I've tried various incantations - 25185387f, 25185387.0, 25185387*1.0, to_number(25185387), etc.

As I read the docs, BINARY_FLOAT should store to 1.79e308, so it can't be a rounding problem.

I'm using Oracle 11.2.0.3 on a 64-bit platform.

Ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since the implementation of the oracle is BINARY_FLOAT standard ieee 754. BINARY_FLOAT is same as [singe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

single have only 23 bits for significant bits.

25185387 = 11000000001001100011010 **11** (length = 25)

25185388 = 11000000001001100011011 **00** (length = 25)

hence the importance of these oracle rounds, discarding the least significant bits

25185387 ~ 11000000001001100011011 * 2^2

25185388 ~ 11000000001001100011011 * 2^2

so get the same value

Comment: Interesting...the Oracle docs...

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#i140176

...say a BINARY_FLOAT has a "maximum positive finite value" of 3.40282E+38F (I'd mispasted earlier).  

So I was assuming I could store a number up to that size.  Now I see what you mean.

So is the largest integer I could store 2^23?

Thanks again for the great answer.

Comment: 2^23 without losing precision. Rounding occurs with increasing. Signification bit save in [normalize form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_number). Oracle also store `exponent` component of number in 8 bits (exponent sign + 7 bits). maximum number = 2^(2^7) * 1.111..111 ≈ 3.4 * 10^38